# 718 error number while connecting to server

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, l2tp

i have configured nttac+ to my server and set authentication to radious server , 
but when i want to connect to my server through l2tp i get 718 error number !

log file of nttac is :

```
#24-02-2013 19:09:20# RAD_ATHN 127.0.0.1:52394[19]:chap-authentication query for 'moslem' accepted
#24-02-2013 19:15:58 DEBUG# Backlog value is:0
```

when i set authentication to windows works good but throght radious i get an error

Comment: Sorry, we'd need a lot more details. What does the server run, what does the client run? What are the versions of the involved packages? Any log or error messages? Everything up to date?

Comment: windows server 2008 R2 , l2tp protocol with preshared key, error number Error 718 : The connection was terminated because the remote computer did not respond in a timely manner